# CSV to XLXS format with data in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an `.csv` file in which data is in below format
`TEST;"TEST1";"TEST2";"TEST3";"TEST4"` in each column.

I need to convert `.csv` file to `.xlsx` file in which each value should in different column. eg:See attached image.

I tried using Apache POI however, its just converting into `.xlsx` format but data remains in one column.

Can you anyone share sample code.

Sample input in csv
[image: input sample]

Below is the sample output result which should in xlsx format.
[image: output sample]

Comment: semicolon (;) is not a comma (,). csv means comma separated values

Comment: @Lino: double quotes is required if data contains a comma/newline/etc

Comment: Thanks for your input guys.. I have attached the data format in the existing .csv file. Output result also i have attached.

Comment: POI will put the data in whatever column you tell it. So it's your job to split the input data and distribute it over the columns you want.

Comment: Thanks piet. Do you have any sample code for the same. That will help me understanding the process of doing that.

Comment: @user3406322: try replacing semicolon between values to a comma. then apply your current code and see if it worked.

Comment: @user3406322: or if possible re-generate the csv file giving the value separator explicitly as comma and use that file to get converted.

Comment: @Ravinder Reddy: It worked however out is coming like below:           "0201 45127 Essen 22 Alfrediquelle" in excel file. " is appending at the start and end.    Below is my logic                                                                                          while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String str[] = currentLine.split(",");
            RowNum++;
            XSSFRow currentRow=sheet.createRow(RowNum);
            for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
                currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(str[i]);
            }
        }

Comment: @user3406322: i fear you are not reading the csv file using poi. unless which you are not going to get correct result.

Comment: @RavinderReddy Is POI actually capable of reading csv? I would always read csv as normal text files using standard java means and parse them accordingly (remove separators, quotes etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple example (without exception handling, encoding, file paths, ...) that could handle CSV with semicolons (in that case `csv` translates to "character separated file") and creates a Xslx file:

```
//open input file
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.csv"));
//create sheet
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
//read from file
String line = br.readLine();
for (int rows=0; line != null; rows++) {
    //create one row per line
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rows);
    //split by semicolon
    String[] items = line.split(";");
    //ignore first item
    for (int i=1, col=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        //strip quotation marks
        String item = items[i].substring(1, items[i].length()-1);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(col++);
        //set item
        cell.setCellValue(item);
    }
    //read next line
    line = br.readLine();
}
//write to xlsx
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Output.xlsx");
wb.write(out);
//close resources
br.close();
out.close();
```

Given an input.csv like this:

```
TEST;"TEST1";"TEST2";"TEST3";"TEST4"
TEST;"TEST5";"TEST6";"TEST7";"TEST8"
```

the Output.xlsx looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked somewhat but output contains "TEST" in each row. it should be only TEST.

Comment: I tried manipulating item variable in the above code snippet ,however its value still exists as "TEST" and I am not able to remove "" & send only TEST in the excel column. Can you advice here?

Comment: @user3406322 If the output of your code is not as described above, you should do some debugging or logging to find out the cause.

Comment: Thanks mate!!!. I already fixed the issue in your sample code & was able to get the expected result.